# Compare two file systems between Solaris and Linux

Tags: linux, solaris, rsync

I am trying a source to target file comparison between Solaris and Linux. 
  - I have a large number of files > 3000
  - Large number of directories  > 600
  - Directory structure remains same
  - I need to verify the ACL's [ getfacl]
  - Permissions, owner, group
  - File data
Need to make sure the files in Linux are in sync with solaris.

What would be the optimum way for this task. I have tried manual comparison using a list, rsh , diff, rsync and  None of them really  supports ACL. 
Is is possible using rsync? I have tried rsync as
rsync --dry-run -vrc remote:source target  - Am I missing something here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done using

rsync -virlogpAcn source target